# HP PAVILLION DV1000 INSTALLING UBUNTU

Tags: hp-pavilion

Downloaded  Ubuntu-17.04-desktop-i386.iso

Used Imgburn to burn iso to DVD from Windows Vista x64.

All went well until I tried to boot the dvd from the HP Pavilion DV1000 that currently has no hard drive installed, only a DVD / DVR recorder/player.

Upon bootup the DVD player/recorder light blinks several times and then nothing. Screen is black.

So I need to burn from another OS such as Ubuntu 64 bit I have installed on a USB Drive? Use another iso burner, other?

Perhaps backup to an earlier version of Ubuntu?

The HP Pavilion DV1000 has Intel Pentium M CPU - 2000 MHz, 1024MB main memory, 128MB Video memory, Bios Version F.11

Answer (score 0):

After installing the iso from Ubuntu the DVD was able to boot up running Ubuntu.

Anyway everything works as expected. I picked the DV1000 up at a garage sale for 10 bucks, came with a  nice laptop bag worth $10.00. The HP Pavilion DV1000 has multimedia features such as playing music, mp3s, dvd movies, etc.

Runs XP so doesn't require alot of system resources.  Not as nearly as  powerful as newer Pavilions. Besides multimedia apps perhaps could be used for other things such as gps, mapping, etc.